# Messed up Rails installation (OS X)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had already installed rails 1.8.7, forgot about it, then installed 1.9.3 through RVM. I was getting weird errors, so I purged my Mac of the system version of Ruby and started again using RVM. So far I've

Installed Ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p0
which ruby
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
```

Manually setup Rubygems

```
which gem
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/gem
```

Tried to install rails

```
sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.2.1
1 gem installed
gem list
rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0)
```

It says rails is installed, but `which gem` does not work, and when I try to use `rails new` I get:

```
-bash: rails: command not found
```

I'm definitely missing something here. The only explanation I can think of is that there are remnants of a previous ruby or rails install that's causing problems. Is there a way to start completely from scratch?

Comment: Uninstalling your system version of Ruby (1.8.7) is definitely a bad idea.  Try doing a `rails -v`, if nothing returns try `rvmsudo gem install rails`.

Comment: `rvmsudo gem install rails` was an improvement, because it showed it was downloading all the rails files, but immediately after `31 gems installed` I tried `rails new x` and got `command not found` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using RVM, you should not use "sudo" when you install gems. That will install gems to your system ruby version (not on the RVM rubies).

First, set up default rvm ruby like

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0 --default
```

Then, install rails on it by running:

```
gem install rails -v=3.2.1
```

It's actually better to use gemsets so you can have different gems set for the same ruby version. Check [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) for more info.

Comment: I'm getting: `-bash-3.2$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0 --default
Using /Users/Nathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
-bash-3.2$ gem install rails-3.2.1
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails-3.2.1' (>= 0) in any repository`.

Comment: try gem install rails -v=3.2.1   I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled Lion. RVM gave me this error: `checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in '/Users/User/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`. I ended up installing RubyGems and Rails on top of system ruby and it's working. Thanks for your help anyway.